# why php from web broswer doesn't find a file that has special characters

Tags: shell, web, encoding, escaping, filenames

I need to manipulate the openldap server database file for an app feature. I noticed that on shell it can find the openldap database file olcDatabase={1}bdb.ldif. But when I run the script from web browser from a windows host, it can not find the file. So I wrote my test script as below.

```
    <?php

    $filename = '/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={1}bdb.ldif';            

    file_put_contents('/var/log/file_path_data', realpath($filename));                                                    

    if (file_exists($filename))    
        echo "find the file";      
    else  
        echo "don't find the file";  

    ?>
```

When it is run from web, it can not find the file at all and escaping special characters doesn't help. I also used %3D or \x3D to replace "=" in file path for example (see http://www.ascii-code.com/), but it doesn't help either. There is no any single error reported from web browswer when it can not find the file.

This may be related to utf8 encoding or something like this in windows environment but i m not able to figure out how to fix this problem. Highly apprecitate any tips and solutions. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Can you show the actual code you're using and post the specific error message you're getting?

Comment: Thanks. yeah, i noticed the code was not added there. i m trying to update my question.

Comment: The problem was resolved. The problem is the permission issue with openldap database file, not the special characters in database file path.

Answer (score -1):

At first just try read your file from a little bit less subdirectories.
When you find out whats chars your web server don't handle

For example create this test files :

1) $filename = '/etc/openldap/slapd.d/olcDatabase={1}bdb.ldif';

2) $filename = '/etc/openldap/slapd.d/olcDatabase=bdb.ldif';

And try read them

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Comment: Actually, i have tried $filename = '/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/' and the problem is apparently the special character "=". But this doesn't help anything unless i know how to replace "=" in the file path.

Comment: The problem was resolved. The problem is the permission issue with openldap database file, not the special characters in database file path.